# How to safely access a content asynchronously fetched?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Here is what I am trying to do :
When my application starts, it directly starts an asynchronous call to get some data from a WebService.
Then, I open a second Activity that displays that data.
Simplified code :
Activity 1 :

```
OnPostExecute()
{               
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); ++i)
    { JSONObject jsonTrack = jsonTrackArray.getJSONObject(i);
                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                Content content = new Content(jsonObject.getString("content"),
                MyApp.contentList.add(Content);
         }
}
```

Second Activity :

```
doSomething (contentList.get(0));
```

How can I make sure that when I try to access to contentList(0) that it has already been fetched by the AsynTask ?

Comment: could you clarify:  how to temporize while I am waiting for the content to load and retry to access ?

Comment: Think about how you are going to populate contentList?  You are in the second activity here.  Are you planning to pass it from the first activity or store it somewhere? Putting the list in MyApp is probably not the right place. It requires you to extend the base class Application which is not a recommended practice.

Comment: I have clarified my question by removing that part, thinking about how to temporize while i get the result from the webservice was the wrong way to go indeed. Instead I will have the two activity bind to the service that use this data and the second activity will check whether the data is here yet or not at startup, if it is -> call to the function that needs this data. If not, a broadcast listener will call the function when the data is fetched.

Comment: Could you explain why I should not use the Application class as a singleton please ? I have seen it done many times and thought in fact that it was a good practice.
after some researchs it seems that the Application can be destroyed when the app is in the background, is it the issue ?
Also, what should I use as a replacement to store application level data ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll probably want to either leave in user in the first activity until the operation is complete or move this logic to a service and broadcast upon completion and set some flag the second activity can check on its lifecycle creation methods.

```
scenario 1:
activity1 starts service then launches activity2.
Service completes, saves a preference, and broadcasts a success message.
activity2 receives this and does its thing.

scenario 2:
User comes back later to activity2, it's onResume checks a preference flag and knows the data exists, so it does its thing.
```

Comment: Broadcast seems to be the answer I was looking for indeed.
I was launching that work as soon as the second activity was launched (well, to be precise, as soon as it was binded to a service which does this work). I think I have a couple of good ideas as of how to handle this elegantly. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Start a loading dialog the moment you kick off the request and only turn it off once you get the response or an error.  If you need to store a status sharable across activities just place it in a SharedPreference, and check it there.  Most likely you will just keep user on the same activity until the operation completes, but if you want to allow them to switch to next activity, you can pass information about the request in the intent (a parameter you add to the intent) you use to start the next activity.  So the data really needs to be either passed via intent to the second activity or stored in a central location where the second activity can access it.

Just noticed you are putting it in the Application class. Not recommended.  I would store it somewhere else like SharedPreference or Database.

If you want non-modal dialog you can use the progress widget instead.  You can put this right in the header off your list btw.

Also please be aware of the startActivityForResult() option.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Why is it not recommended to store this data in the Application Class ?
it seems to fit the central location description ^^. It is not a huge chunk of data either, just a List of ~50 elements which are 6 fields (strings, int, nothing too big)